# Error while creating channel unknown consortium

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create a custom network setup, using first-network sample as a template. Everything goes well, but when i try to create channel from `cli` container, i get this error

```
2018-05-11 11:33:13.956 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2018-05-11 11:33:13.956 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-11 11:33:13.957 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0ABF060A1408021A0608F9FED5D70522...5CB2E57136F84747C182E82B76191345 
2018-05-11 11:33:13.957 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: 6B8E0CAC07B99E8E993D0C4C8692797D12AECD3CA09C56AF07D769B2B0783DD1 
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Unknown consortium name: DocChain
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
  -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
  -t, --timeout int
```

An excerpt from my from my `configtx.yaml` file

```
Profiles:

    DocChainOrdererGenesis: #TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererNUSTOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            DocChain:
                Organizations:
                    - *NUST
                    - *GIKI
                    - *LUMS
    DocChainOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: DocChain
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *NUST
                - *GIKI
                - *LUMS
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks evryone,
I don't know why but renaming `DocChain` to `DocChainConsortium` work for me.

Comment: Just renaming (and rebuilding genesis block and channel creation transaction) does not work for me. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it running this command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down --volumes --remove-orphans`, where the docker-compose yaml files are.
I am not sure what caused the problem, but I think that I hadn't deleted the docker volumes correctly.